# Не работает команда "manage.py" в Pycharm. Начало проекта на Django

Tags: python, django, pycharm, powershell

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]После нажатия manage.py вылетает эта ошибка. пробовал отключить в повершелл запреты под администратором - не помогает. если вводить просто ./manage.py - нет ошибки, но и ничего не происходит. плюс дальнейшие команды в связке с manage.py тоже работают некорректно. Уже третий вечер после работы ищу в гугле, где может быть ошибка. Спасайте, товарищи, need help.

Comment: столкнулся с точно такой же проблемой, вы смогли разобраться в чем тут дело?

Comment: в общем варианта два для решения. первый это я подзабил и решил пойти путём создания виртуального окружения, но потом позже выяснил и первопричину. всё-таки путь криво забил в систему:
- В строке "Поиск" выполните поиск: Система (Панель управления)
- Нажмите на ссылку Дополнительные параметры системы.
- Нажмите Переменные среды. ...
- В окне Изменение системной переменной (или Новая системная переменная) укажите значение переменной среды PATH .
далее в этот путь еще нужно провалиться и проверить, что всё ровно встало, почему-то этот момент не подсвечивают обычно

Answer (score 0):

PS C:\Users\Владислав\myDjangoProject\my_page> python manage.py
File "C:\Users\Владислав\myDjangoProject\my_page\manage.py", line 1
#!/usr/bin/env python
^
SyntaxError: unexpected character after line continuation character

Comment: все основные очевидные и не очень вариации уже пробовал, не работает.(((

Comment: Покажите, какая ошибка появляется при вводе вышеприведенной команды.

Comment: PS C:\Users\Владислав\myDjangoProject\my_page> python manage.py File "C:\Users\Владислав\myDjangoProject\my_page\manage.py", line 1 #!/usr/bin/env python ^ SyntaxError: unexpected character after line continuation character

Comment: прописал ошибку при вводе python manage.py

Answer (score 0):

Откройте `cmd` (для этого нажмите Windows+R, введите `cmd` и нажмите Enter), с помощью команды `cd` перейдите в папку проекта и введите

```
python manage.py <аргументы>...
```

Comment: немного не туда отписал первый раз, но ошибка в cmd та же, что и в пайчарме(ниже). мне теперь кажется он manage.py как командлет не распознает, т.е дело в этом, а не в повершелл

Answer (score 0):

python manage.py runserver - верная вариация, если не сработает - проверьте путь через copyPath, в котором находится файл manage.py.

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]. в частности, стоит пояснить, что именно вы подразумеваете под действием «проверить путь».